# Screen Splash deje de cargar cuando ha cargado la web

Tags: android

Tengo en mi app un Screen Splash y luego un webview. Mi duda es sobre alguna función que haga al Screen Splash desaparecer, no después del tiempo que tengo configurado, sino una vez carga la web en el webview (los webview cargan en fragmentos adentro del main).

Screen Splash

```
 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private final int DURACION_SPLASH = 4000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            };
        }, DURACION_SPLASH);
    }
}
```

Fragmento de webview

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    WebView wv = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl("www.google.es");
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir un `WebViewClient` y usar el método `onPageFinished()` para determinar si se termino de cargar la url en el WebView y de esta forma cerrar la `Activity` :

```
WebView wv = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.wv);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        ...
        ...
        ...
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //Cierra Activity.
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Buenas. En primer lugar muchas gracias por responder, estoy bastante perdido... ¿Eso lo tendría que implementar en el apartado del ScreenSplash? En dicha clase no tengo ningún WebView, ¿tendría que crear uno en el xml del ScreenSplash, y quitar la variable de los 3000 milisegundos?